# datamember didn't point me to its synonym!

Tags: discussion, tags

While posting a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444145/what-is-the-correct-term-for-the-list-that-initializes-the-data-members-in-a-con), I wanted to use a tag for data members. Two tags exist: [datamember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datamember) and [data-members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-members). I thought that one was redundant, since it didn't point to its synonym:

[image]

Shouldn't it mention its synonym? Because it created some confusion. I chose [data-members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-members), and then the other tag was used in my question, I thought I did a mistake.

Comment: I am not sure @Stijn, since I tried fixing that synonym absence by myself before posting here, but I was afraid that I would create a mess, since it's a long time since I edited a tag..

Comment: Figured out how it works. If you type *data-members*, then [datamember] will also be shown with the "also:data-members" text. If you type *datamember*, the "also:..." text doesn't show up.

Comment: Is that the expected behavior @Stijn? I didn't think I should have done that, I mean how would I knew? I wanted to ask about data members, so I started typing, and the auto-complete suggested [tag:datamember] first...

Comment: It's probably working as designed, some tags have a lot of synonyms so listing them all would be impractical. But I agree the user experience is not ideal here.

Comment: Next post: burninate [tag:datamember]?